# vuejs "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I have a input box and user have to give their facebook user id on that so i make input box with default value https://www.facebook.com and then user give their user-profile-link then it will update data but i got this error when anything gonna type on input box

```
<div class="column">
  <label class="label">Facebook Id::</label>
  <input class="input is-medium" type="text" v-model="'https://www.facebook.com/'+data.fblink">
</div>
```

```
<script>
    import contactInfo from './ContactInfo'

    export default {
        components: {contactInfo},
        props: ['data'],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

binding is for variables only, use this it works

```
<div class="column">
  <label class="label">Facebook Id::</label>
  <input class="input is-medium" type="text" v-model="facebook_link">
</div>
```

in your data variable add facebook_link as string. then if you want to update use this

```
'https://www.facebook.com/'+facebook_variable
```

Comment: works good when user allready have a fb id link  then its show https://www.facebook.com/userlink  in input box but at first when user dont have fb id link it shows like that https://www.facebook.com/null as my mysql column is nullable so it shows like that i want to show user like that in input box https://www.facebook.com/ when he doesnt have any fb link..can it possible?

Comment: solved this by adding empty string to database fb field :P

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` needs a variable to bind to, not a fixed string.

```
...
 <input v-model="fbProfileLink"/>
...

export default {
    components: {contactInfo},
    props: ['data'],
    data() {
      return {
        fbProfileLink: 'https://www.facebook.com/'
      }
    }
}
```

If you're making any requests to that link though, you probably shouldn't let the user manipulate it freely but put guards in place so you won't be making requests to a user provided URL blindly.